# How to delete a record using Spring MVC and annotations

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am relatively new to Spring and I am trying to accomplish the following:

Let's say I have a list of fruits in a database table with 2 columns "id" and "name". I would like to have a page displaying the list and have a "delete" button next to each fruit. I thought that would be easy to accomplish but I can't figure it out and can't find any tutorial explaining this.

This is what I have for now:

View:

```
<c:forEach items="${fruits}" var="fruit">
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${fruit.name}" /></td>
        <sec:authorize access="hasRole('admin')">
            <td>
                <a href="<c:url var="deleteUrl" value="/fruit/remove.html"/>">DELETE</a>
                <form id="${fruitFormId}" method="POST">
                    <input id="fruit" name="fruit" type="hidden" value="${fruit.id}"/>
                </form>
            </td>
        </sec:authorize>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Then the controller:

```
@Controller
public class FruitController{

    @Autowired
    private FruitManager fruitManager;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getFruits(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("fruits", this.fruitManager.getFruits());
        return "list";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/fruit/remove", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String removeAd(Fruit fruit) {
        fruitManager.removeFruit(fruit);
        return "/list";
    }
```

I am not even sure I am using the "good and clean" way right now and would like to accomplish this "the right way", following conventions if any.

Comment: What you are using at Persistent layer? JDBC Template, Hibernate or JPA?

Comment: @Ajinkya :I am using JDBC (my dao class extends JdbcDaoSupport). In future I would like to try to use Hibernate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You code is correct, except two small problems:
 - you will not recivce the `fruit` but the `fruitId`. 
 - you need a HTML form with an send button instead of the link

So you will need to correct you controller a bit.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/fruit/remove", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String removeAd(@RequestParam("fruit") long fruitId) {
    Fruit fruit = fruitManager.loadById(fruitId);
    fruitManager.removeFruit(fruit);
    //or
    fruitManager.removeFruitById(fruitId);
    return "redirct:/list";
}
```

*Then I would recommend to redirect after an POST (instead of direct return the list page), so you will not have a problem if the user press the Browser refesh button after he deletes a fruit.*

For the HTML stuff you do not need any JQuery or JavaScript, except you want some delete confirmation message.

```
<c:url var="deleteUrl" value="/fruit/remove.html"/>    
<form id="${fruitFormId}" action="${deleteUrl}" method="POST">
      <input id="fruit" name="fruit" type="hidden" value="${fruit.id}"/>
      <input type="submit" value="delete" onClick="return confirm('sure?')"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer, I have it working now. Do you think I can add another method in the same controller in order to be able to modify a fruit? Is there some coding conventions to follow? Like having a FruitModifyController with only one method, then a FruitDeleteController... or can I do everything in the FruitController directly?

Comment: I have all the create/read/update/delete/list methods in one controller. This works for me since two years.

Answer (score 0):

That's easy, buddy. You just bind an ajax function to the delete button with Jquery or something else, but first I want to confirm you project can run well in tomcat. One problem I found in you code is that the method removeAd(Fruit fruit). you can pass an object Fruit with http, you can just get the Id of fruit. change the method to removeAd(String id). and in the method, you can use reqest.getParameter() to get the value.
This is the tutorial that I recommend: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-spring3/index.html.